# Retrieve an Eloquent Model Based on It's Many to Many Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Say I have a Blog Model, Post Model and a Photo Model.

- A Blog can have many Posts.
- A Post belongs to a Blog.
- A Post belongs to Many Photos.
- A Photo belongs to Many Posts.

```
posts Table
id | blog_id | text

photos Table
id | text

photo_post Table
post_id | photo_id
```

What I'm trying to do is find a specific post on a specified blog where there are two specific photos on it.

I'm struggling with retrieving this Post record with Eloquent.

```
    $post = Post::where('blog_id', $blog->id)
        ->whereHas('photos', function($q) {
            $q->where('photo_id', 180)->where('photo_id', 181);
        })->firstOrFail();
```

There is only ever one instance per blog where the two photos are used in a single post.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing with the query

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: I've verified in the db the records are there to pull this.

Comment: When you do `$q->where('photo_id', 180)->where('photo_id', 181);` it's like `WHERE photo_id = 180 AND photo_id = 181` so naturally it won't work. Have posted an answer using `whereIn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereIn`

```php
$post = Post::where('blog_id', $blog->id)
    ->whereHas('photos', function($q) {
        $q->whereIn('photo_id', [180, 181]);
    })
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: This works. I'll accept it in a few mins when it lets me. :P Thanks

Comment: Can you do a firstOrCreate there?

Comment: @ahackney No can't do. firstOrCreate has a signature of firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values) where $attributes contain $key => $value pairs against which a search is done on existing records in db. If a record is not found then a new record with $values is created. In your case if you want to check whether a post exists with which two photos with given id's are associated or not and if not create a new Post record - you can write first instead of firstOrFail. Then if $post (returned by first()) is null create a new record